# Qt trying to enable scrolling slightly beyond last element in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a sort of an Excel-type application in which I can load a tab-delimited text file and I am able to edit cells... etc

It's useable but I have an issue related to me allowing the user to "freeze" a number of columns/rows. ("Frozen" rows/columns can only be one of the first ones and are then "frozen", i.e. always displayed even when scrolling)

The whole frozen Col/Row is working but I would like the user to be able to scroll slightly past the last Col/Row in order to be able to only ever display full cells.

Right now when reaching the end of the scrollbar I end up with a partial leftmost column and topmost row because it's only displaying up to the last full col/row and not going a wee bit further for all content to be displayed fully.

[image: Picture of what's happening]

I've tried doing adding some space to the maximum scrollbar value once everything is loaded in the table but it seems to have no effect :

```
table->horizontalScrollBar()->setMaximum(table->horizontalScrollBar()->maximum() + t->horizontalScrollBar()->singleStep()*2);
```

I tried multiple values too.

(Edit) There may be some Qt code that "snaps" the QTableView viewport back to the edge of the last cell automatically...

(Edit2) I connected verticalScrollbar's `rangeChanged()` signal to a custom slot with the following code:

```
void MyTableView::onRangeChanged(int min, int max) {
  QScrollBar *sender = verticalScrollBar();
  int newVMax = max + 20;
  sender->blockSignals(true);
  sender->setRange(min, newVMax);
  sender->blockSignals(false);
}
```

Sadly there is definitely a snapback mechanic when scrolling to the end of verticalScrollbar...

[Gif of snap back issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irwsy.gif)

(Edit3) The snap back may be related to:

```
void QHeaderViewPrivate::setScrollOffset(const QScrollBar *scrollBar, QAbstractItemView::ScrollMode scrollMode)
{
    Q_Q(QHeaderView);
    if (scrollMode == QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerItem) {
        if (scrollBar->maximum() > 0 && scrollBar->value() == scrollBar->maximum())
            q->setOffsetToLastSection();
        else
            q->setOffsetToSectionPosition(scrollBar->value());
    } else {
        q->setOffset(scrollBar->value());
    }
}
```

mainly:

```
if (scrollBar->maximum() > 0 && scrollBar->value() == scrollBar->maximum())
    q->setOffsetToLastSection();
```

Comment: Have you tried having one extra (empty/fake) column and row that will be only partially displayed when you have scrolled to end?

Comment: Hmm then I'd probably need to code the functionality in MyTableView (very inventive subclass name haha) so that they're a visual/fake col/row pair that cannot accept data (?)
It sounds like it could work and thank you for the suggestion, but it doesn't seem very elegant.
I've been looking at the Qt Documentation, and as an alternative I would probably need to reimplement QTableView's `scrollContentsBy()` which is most likely out of my league.